# How to show other columns in Windows DHCP server?

Tags: windows-server-2012, dhcp

In the Windows Server DHCP server, the only column that shows for "Reservations" is the "Reservations" column.  That's not very helpful.  It would be so much more helpful if I could see the description and the mac address.

When I go to "Customize Columns" there is no option to add anything to the view.

Is there any way to get the other columns to become available to the column editor, or is this one of those typical Microsoft feature-failures?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the GUI at least you don't get any additional options, you basically have to open the properties of the reservation.

Since it's 2012, you could use:

`Get-DhcpServerv4Reservation`

or

`Get-DhcpServerv6Reservation`

in Powershell with whatever parameters are available with the command or just the `| fl`.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj590708.aspx

Comment: What good is a GUI????  That really gets my ire up.  A GUI to display the appropriate columns is wonderful - why, oh why, Microsoft do you do things like that?

Comment: Yes, I have read about the powershell command, and I've read where other people said the GUI doesn't show it, but I was hoping someone would have a hack or fix for that dumb issue.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not aware of (never really looked) any workaround or 3rd party GUI that can handle it.

Comment: One more pipe and you can get a "GUI" from Powershell: `Get-DhcpServerv4Reservation -ScopeId 192.168.0.0 | Out-GridView`

Comment: This is the only real answer, I think.  I ended up, however, installing a dhcp helper to point to a linux dhcp server on my other subnet...  Otherwise I would have to memorize all those powershell commands!

Comment: :) sorry mate...MS doesn't assume you'll be getting back into that section of the GUI often I suppose.